# How can I fix this syntax error with heruko

Tags: git

I keep running into this error every time I try to push my code into heroku and can't seem to see what is wrong. This is the error I am getting

```
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected string key before ':' at line 12, column 10
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
```

This is my code in package.json

```
{
  "name": "manuela",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "needed package",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:nela94/PetMe.git",
  "author": "<github username> <<github email address>>",
  "license": "MIT"
}

"scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && yarn install && yarn build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "postinstall": "yarn build && yarn deploy && echo 'Client built!''"
  },
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "1.15.2",
    "npm": "6.9.0",
    "node": "11.8.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` seems to be off by a bracket and a comma.

Try this

```
{
  "name": "manuela",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "needed package",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:nela94/PetMe.git",
  "author": "<github username> <<github email address>>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && yarn install && yarn build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "postinstall": "yarn build && yarn deploy && echo 'Client built!''"
  },
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "1.15.2",
    "npm": "6.9.0",
    "node": "11.8.0"
  }
}
```